# Want to display All User DorpDown List in Quick Edit Section in custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type, edit

I want to display users dropdown in quick edit section. But i don't know how can i add.

Please help me.
I have attached image where i need that dropdown.

[image]

Comment: If you logged in with other capable user to edit other posts then who created that posts then you can see author dropdown to quick edit, let me know if it make sense or not i.e you have **User A** and **User B** and you had created posts from **User A** then to see author box you need to logged in with **User B** and check

**NOTE: That user must have capability to edit that posts/post type**

Answer (score 0):

I know this way :

First select the post by left checkbox, on the top in BulkAction dropdown select Edit then Apply -- > now you can change the author

Comment: I need to get all user in author dropdown.